# Fazer debug das SharedPreferences no Android

Tags: android

Existe alguma maneira fácil de ver tudo o que tenho dentro das minhas `SharedPreferences`?
Algo como por exemplo:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "user_access", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Log.i("SharedPreferences", prefs);
```

**Update**
Com a ajuda de @Piovezan consegui utilizando o seguinte código:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "user_access", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> prefs_map = prefs.getAll();

Log.i("debug", prefs_map.toString());
```

Comment: Se você olhar a [API de SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), verá que existe um médodo `getAll()` que retorna um `Map` com os pares chave-valor contidos nas preferences.

Comment: @Piovezan, por que não posta como resposta? Pra mim isso responde a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você olhar a [API de SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), verá que existe um médodo `getAll()` que retorna um `Map` com os pares chave-valor contidos nas preferences.